# Did Thomas and Martha fund Carmine Falcone in the comics?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

I recently finished [Batman: The Telltale Series'](http://store.steampowered.com/app/498240/) first episode (Realm of Shadows).

> The episode ends with Bruce (as Batman) finding a photograph where his parents are entertaining Carmine Falcone to drinks. Furthermore, Falcone admits to having been funded by the Waynes' since the start.

Is this backed by any comic volumes? Or is the story a spin-off in the DCverse?